# Saving an retrieving sound on Parse.com

Tags: ios, audio, parse-platform

I am trying to download some short sound file on Parse.com in an iOS application.
The file has previously been saved using the following code:

```
    NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
    parse_Sound = [PFFile fileWithName:@"XXYYZZ"
                                  data:soundData];
    [parse_Sound saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!succeeded) {
                NSLog(@"sound-upload NG”);
        } else {
                NSLog(@"sound-upload OK");
            }];
        }
    }];
```

Seeing the message on the debugging console, it appearently works.
Now what kind of code do I need to run to retrieve(download) the sound file?
I have browsed the net, but found nothing clear and working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get data back from the server you need to need to run a query asking for that object but you haven't associated the uploaded file with a column in any Class yet.  Uploading a PFFile is iOS is a two step process:

1) Upload the PFFile to the server

2) In the callback associated the PFFile with a column in a data object

```
NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
    parse_Sound = [PFFile fileWithName:@"XXYYZZ"
                                  data:soundData];
    [parse_Sound saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!succeeded) {
                NSLog(@"sound-upload NG”);
        } else {
                NSLog(@"sound-upload OK");

                PFObject *soundStuff = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Sounds"];

                soundStuff[@"soundFile"] = parse_Sound;
                [soundStuff saveInBackground];

            }];
        }
    }];
```

Now to get the data back you would run a query on the Sounds class that will have the sound data in the soundFile column:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Sounds"];
[query whereKey:@"someKey" equalTo:@"someValue"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    // The find succeeded.

    // Do something with the found objects
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
        PFFile *soundFile = object[@"soundFile"];
        NSData *soundData = [soundFile getData];

    }
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  }
}];
```

I haven't tested any of this code but it at least demonstrates the steps needed and should get you started.

Here are the examples from the [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#files-classes/iOS):

```
PFObject *jobApplication = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"JobApplication"]
jobApplication[@"applicantName"] = @"Joe Smith";
jobApplication[@"applicantResumeFile"] = file;
[jobApplication saveInBackground];
```

Then to get the data back:

```
PFFile *applicantResume = anotherApplication[@"applicantResumeFile"];
NSData *resumeData = [applicantResume getData];
```

Notice that `file` is being associated with the `applicantResumeFile` column of the `JobApplication` class so that the file data can be retrieved in queries.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a reference to that file somewhere (ideally in a column of the `PFObject` it belongs to).

If you don't keep a reference you're out of luck and you can't retrieve already uploaded files that have no association to any object.

I suggest you read through the Parse documentation for files on iOS https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#files/iOS